# Defining root and error routes in NodeJs/Express

Tags: node.js, express

I defined some routes for my application. Like

```
app.get('/page1', function (req, res) {
    res.render('page1');
});

app.get('/page2', function (req, res) {
    res.render('page2');
});
```

and if the route is missing or wrong, the application should always redirect to another page. I want to define a root route:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('notFound'); // redirect to a 404 template
});
```

and what do I have to define to cover all the error or missing pages?

When having `'/page1/abcdefgh'` and `'/fooBar'` both routes should redirect to the `res.render('notFound');` template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle a `404` place a `*` route-handler below all pre-defined routes. So if none of your predefined routes will match (like `/page1` or `/page2`), the `*` will get triggered.

```
// Will match /page1
app.get('/page1', function (req, res) {
    res.render('page1');
});

// Will match /page2
app.get('/page2', function (req, res) {
    res.render('page2');
});

// Will be triggered if nothing above got a match
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.render('notFound'); // redirect to a 404 template
});
```

Comment: ah, this is very helpful